# problem in read ssl data using openssl library in c

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl

This program uses openssl to secure  http connection :

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


#define IP_ADDR INADDR_ANY
#define PORT 8081

int password_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *password);

EVP_PKEY *generatePrivateKey();
X509 *generateCertificate(EVP_PKEY *pkey);

/**
* Example SSL server that accepts a client and echos back anything it receives.
* Test using `curl -I https://127.0.0.1:8081 --insecure --sslv3`
*/
int main(int arc, char **argv)
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("opening socket\n");

        return -4;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;
    bzero((char *)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr));
    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = IP_ADDR;
    s_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("binding\n");
        return -5;
    }

    listen(fd, 2);

    int cfd;    
    while (cfd = accept(fd, 0, 0))
    {
        SSL_load_error_strings();
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();

        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        SSL_library_init();

        SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_server_method());
        //SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());
        if (ctx == NULL) {      
            printf("errored; unable to load context.\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return -3;
        }

        EVP_PKEY *pkey = generatePrivateKey();
        X509 *x509 = generateCertificate(pkey);

        SSL_CTX_use_certificate(ctx, x509);
        SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, password_cb);
        SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey(ctx, pkey);

        RSA *rsa=RSA_generate_key(512, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL); 
        SSL_CTX_set_tmp_rsa(ctx, rsa); 
        RSA_free(rsa);

        SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, 0);

        SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

        BIO *accept_bio = BIO_new_socket(cfd, BIO_CLOSE);
        SSL_set_bio(ssl, accept_bio, accept_bio);

        SSL_accept(ssl);

        BIO *bio = BIO_pop(accept_bio);

        char buf[1024];
        FILE *file1 = fopen("logfile", "a");

        while (1)
        {
            // first read data

            int r = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1024);
            ERR_print_errors_fp(file1);

            printf ("\nsize of read data : %d\n", r);

            printf ("actual data : %s\n", buf);

            switch (SSL_get_error(ssl, r))
            { 
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE: 
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN: 
                goto end; 
            default: 
                printf("SSL read problem");
                goto end;
            }

            int len = r;

            // now keep writing until we've written everything
            int offset = 0;
            while (len)
            {
                r = SSL_write(ssl, buf + offset, len); 
                switch (SSL_get_error(ssl, r))
                { 
                case SSL_ERROR_NONE: 
                    len -= r;
                    offset += r; 
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("SSL write problem");
                    goto end;
                }
            }
        }

    end:

        SSL_shutdown(ssl);

        BIO_free_all(bio);
        BIO_free_all(accept_bio);
    }

    return 0;
}

int password_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *password)
{
    strncpy(buf, (char *)(password), size);
    buf[size - 1] = '\0';

    return strlen(buf);
}

EVP_PKEY *generatePrivateKey()
{
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(pctx);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(pctx, 2048);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen(pctx, &pkey);

    return pkey;
}

X509 *generateCertificate(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    X509 *x509 = X509_new();
    X509_set_version(x509, 2);
    ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x509), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), (long)60*60*24*365);
    X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);

    X509_NAME *name = X509_get_subject_name(x509);
    X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "C", MBSTRING_ASC, (const unsigned char*)"US", -1, -1, 0);
    X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC, (const unsigned char*)"YourCN", -1, -1, 0);
    X509_set_issuer_name(x509, name);
    X509_sign(x509, pkey, EVP_md5());

    return x509;
}
```

I run the program and connect to it using this command :

```
curl -I https://127.0.0.1:8081 --insecure --sslv3
```

variable *r* is the length of data that *ssl_read* reads and stores them in *buf* variable.when i print them i get these results :

```
r : -1 
buf : �zvԞ
```

The program run correctly on another system with same OS and openssl version.
output of *cat /etc/issue* on both system :

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

output of *openssl version -a* on both system :

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
built on: Wed Sep 25 17:53:16 2019
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

but on the system that has the problem, there is an additional line top of *openssl version -a* output :

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

but openssl.cnf exists in the path. why the program can not read https request correctly ?

**EDIT** the system that has problem is a lxc container that i install openssl on it with copying openssl files and directories.

Comment: *openssl.cnf exists in the path. why the program can not read https request correctly* - Check permissions of file `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`. Maybe it's inaccessible to your library/process.

Comment: i give 777 permission to openssl.conf , but the warning message exists and ssl data can not read.

Comment: @alk the program works correctlly on another system. i think there is no problem with accept

Comment: Forget my previous comment (deleted already). I was confused by the broken indention. Fix this now.

Comment: i don't know this can help or not, but every when i stop the program and run it again, buf is changed. one time �j+�, another time �Jb� ...

Comment: if additional information is required i can provide them.

Comment: the system that has problem is a lxc container that i install openssl on it with copying openssl files and directories. because the system has not access to internet .

Comment: there is no idea ?

Comment: You should check the return value from `SSL_accept` and if not 1 you should check `SSL_get_error` (see [the manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_accept.html) and click on the link to `SSL_get_error`) and if that is `SSL_ERROR_SSL` look at the error queue. (If `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` you should look for an OS error, which for Unix is `errno`.) Also when `SSL_read` returns -1 the same; in that case the contents of the buffer aren't set, which is why printing the contents of the buffer gives you varying and useless info. ...

Comment: ... And even when `SSL_read` succeeds, the data stored is not null-terminated, so treating it as a string is wrong. Also, I hope you realize SSLv3 is broken and totally insecure for years, the export suites (the only ones that used tmp_RSA) have been broken for decades, and MD5 is broken for cert signature for over a decade (although your cert is completely bogus anyway so the signature security doesn't matter)